# Prohibition of Meat and Wine on the 9th of Av

Tags: halacha, meat, grapes-wine, tisha-bav, nine-days

Is there a specific prohibition against the consumption of meat and wine of the 9th of Av besides for the general obligation to fast?

This question makes a difference in the case of someone who is forced to break his / her fast. May said individual consume meant / wine?

I saw a story that the Brisker Rav needed to eat on the 9th of Av that fell out on Sunday. He used that opportunity to make havdalah with wine on motzaei Shabbos (the beginning of the fast). Apparently, he held that there is no prohibition to consume meant and wine onthe 9th of Av itself. What do others hold?

Comment: There is a prohibition at the Seudat Mafseket. The Yerushalmi calls the Seudat Mafseket "Seudat Tisha b'Av" so some have learned that were there to be a meal on Tisha b'Av it would have the same rules, and we just practice the prohibition early out of necessity. Actually I feel like this was the Brisker Rav's point. Could it be you have the story backwards?

Comment: @DoubleAA I presented the story as I heard it. I cannot guarantee the veracity of the story. (Although I personally trust it).

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61489/5323

Comment: @DoubleAA Where is the Yerushalmi?

Comment: @yeh very end of taanit

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. In regards to the "story" about the Brisker Rov. This is a "famous" story that I've heard said over many times. Some going as far to say that the Chazzon Ish held this way as well (to make havdallah on grape juice/wine if one would need to. Never saw it inside or got a makor.) However every Rav I asked this year said (halacha l'maseh) to make on "chomer medina" (which they said was either natural fruit juice or coffee.)