# Havdalah if you have to eat or drink on Tisha B'Av that comes out on Sunday

Tags: tisha-bav, havdalah, nine-days

If a person for whatever reason has to eat and drink on Tisha B'Av that comes out on Sunday, and they know this ahead of time, when should they make havdallah on a cos? Should they make Motzei Shabbos like normally (however omit the other parts of havdallah that are omitted when someone would normally make havdallah on Sunday night after Tisha B'Av.) Should they make havdallah (on cos) only right before they will eat or drink. Or Should they wait and make havdallah (on a cos) Sunday night like everyone else?

Comment: Related (inspiration?) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61484/5323

Comment: @Shokhet Except this only focuses on the when, and skirts the question of what kind of beverage to drink.

Comment: http://www.torahlab.org/Family/article/when_tisha_bav_is_shabbos/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Shaarei Teshuva ([OC 556](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2919)) quotes those who require the ill person to recite Havadala "right away after Shabbat", though as Rav Ovadia Yosef (Yechavveh Daat 3:40) explains while citing many sources, this means as soon as they need to eat NOT right away on Saturday night if they can last until later in the day. This is indeed how Rav Yosef rules.

Comment: If it's done right after Shabbbos should it be done with a candle? (besamim I'm guessing should be skipped.)

Comment: @Yehoshua Yes, per [*Shulchan Aruch* OC 556](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%95) that everyone makes the blessing on the candle on מוצאי שבת anyway. *B'samim* should be skipped due to the enjoyment involved (*M"B* 556:1, though it is a *machlokes haposkim* whether one should avoid smelling fragrant spices all of Tisha B'Av, or just at night - see *Sha'ar HaTziyon* 556:1).

Comment: The Sharei Teshuva is obviously quoting some posek (or perhaps he is not?) Could be improved by adding that in.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Eliezer Barclay Shlita told my father who is going to eat by day to make Havdala just prior to eating in the morning, and omit Besamim and the candle (which was done Motzei Shabbos already).

[Zecher Simcha 69](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1664&st=&pgnum=63) says that one should not make Havdala in such a case unless he needs the wine due to his weakness. However he also brings dissenting opinions that indicate one should make Havdala prior to eating.

Comment: This revision makes sense, though it only applies to someone who isn't eating until the next morning. If a person had to make *havdala* at night, he would presumably make the blessings in order (except for skipping *b'samim*), even if he was going to delay his *havdala* to try to fast for a few hours (per [R' Akiva Eiger OC 298](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1501), [*M"B* 298:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%97), and *Sha'ar HaTziyon* 298:3).

Comment: @Fred RAE doesn't sound so sure, especially given that this night is like Purim in that he has to read something (cf. Taz 566).

Comment: @DoubleAA Correct, but see the *M"B* and *Sha'ar HaTziyon* where the Chafetz Chaim decisively indicates that the custom is to wait and say the blessings in order.

Answer (score 0):

Someone told me that Rabbi Leibowitz told him in the name of Rav Shechter that a person who will certainly be eating should make Havdalah on Shabbos after Plag HaMincha.

It was not clear to the Rabbi who told me this if this was a practical Halachic ruling or a theoretical point.